Get data with selenium from website using extension?
i try to get this informaitons out of the listbox:

using the following code:
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fnExtension = os.path.join(path, "EmailHunter.crx")
WAIT = 2
  
print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  
options.add_extension(fnExtension)  
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
srv=Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

link = f"https://www.orf.at" 
driver.get (link)    
# driver.get("chrome://extensions/?id=mbindhfolmpijhodmgkloeeppmkhpmhc")
# driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('extensions-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#viewManager > extensions-detail-view.active').shadowRoot.querySelector('div#container.page-container > div.page-content > div#options-section extensions-toggle-row#allow-incognito').shadowRoot.querySelector('label#label input').click()");

fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconExtension.png")  
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtensionIcon, confidence=0.5)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)
time.sleep(2)

fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconPin2.png")  
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtensionIcon, confidence=0.5)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)

time.sleep(2)
fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconPin3.png")  
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtensionIcon, confidence=0.5)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)

time.sleep(2)
fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconPin4.png") 
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtensionIcon, confidence=0.3)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)

time.sleep(2)
fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconPin5.png") 
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtensionIcon, confidence=0.3)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)

using the following images using pyautogui





But when i press the Copy / Export button using PyAutoGui the results are not in the clipboard or exported to the default download folder of the chromw browser.
How can i parse or get this found emails from the extension lisbox?

Servus, I don't think it is possible to get the email list with BeautifulSoup since the extension doesn't change the DOM of the original website. But you could try to get the emails by clicking the "Export" or "Copy" button below the emails using Pyautogui.

Thx - i tried to press the copy button - but it seems that the data is not stored in the clipboard after pressing the button in the selenium-chromes instance

I changed the initial question - its possible to press the Copy and Export button - but nothing happens...
